# How many parameters can "return statement" take in C programming?

Tags: c

code snippet code following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int test()
{
    return (printf("it is test\n"), false);
}

int main()
{ 
    if (false == test())
        printf("return result is false\n");
}
```

The return statement works but I don't know why it can work as i didn't encounter the statement before. Can any body help to explain the usage of return statement in this snippet code?

Comment: This is a `C` question and therefore there is no operator overloading.

Comment: @Blaze: That's half an answer. You first need to establish it's parsed as an operator.

Comment: [Can 'return' return multiple values in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3626648/995714), [How does this return statement with multiple values (variables) works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31810832/995714), [Function returning two things seperated by a comma in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24712884/995714), [Can a function return more than one value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27328544/995714)

Comment: there is something called the comma operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737634/c-comma-operator

Comment: Note that `return` is a statement not a function call.  Putting parentheses after it only affects precedence, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the actual main question, exactly one, If you wish to return more you need to pass in a pointer, or return one to a struct, ie:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool test(int * data)
{
    *data = printf("it is test\n");
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int data;
    if (false == test(&data))
        printf("return result is false, data = %d\n", data);
}
```

As for why it works, please see: [Comma-Separated return arguments in C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094189/comma-separated-return-arguments-in-c-function)

Comment: @hellow The actual question in the title asks exactly how many parameters `return` can take, this answer is correct as even with the comma operator, it still only takes one, the right most.

Comment: Please note that structs are values too, so you really don't *need* to use pointers.